# Visualization of axisymmetric flows

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vector-fields, visualization

This question might be vague but I want to get a feeling for axisymmetric flows. In mathematics a vector field $v=v(r,\theta,z)$ where $(r,\theta,z)$ are cylindrical coordinates is axisymmetric if it is indendent of the angle $\theta$. For me this means that any rotation around the $z$ axis leaves the vector field unchanged (for fixed height $z$). I have to admit that I don't think at all I can imagine what this really means.
When I see pictures of flows I can't tell if the flow is axisymmetric or not because my imagination is too planar. I would be grateful for any hints and also pictures, examples of flows with some explanations!

Comment: Suppose you have a straight tube whose diameter varies with axial position along the tube (like a nozzle).

Answer (score 0):

You buy a round-shaped marble cake. A round-shaped cake is roughly a cylinder, and so it is like a pipe (but the diameter is larger then the height).

Now, you take a slice of that cake. Because it is a marble cake, you will see some kind of shape between the light and the dark parts. Now, imagine you take many slices. All slices will look exactly the same. Imagine also the following: if you cut the cake in half, you will see two faces side by side, separated by the axis. These faces need to be symmetric in relation to the axis.

The picture of the marble cake may be good to give an idea for the non-engineer/non-scientist. Yet, it is somehow short, and we need to look a bit further into the symmetry in relation to the axis.

Consider two very long concentric cylinders, with water between them, but no axial flow. Let's say we start rotating the external cylinder. We may get something like this:

[image]

If we look from an horizontal position, and if we plot the signs of the velocity perpendicular to the screen, we will see:

[image]

So, is this flow axisymmetric? No, it isn't. When we see two cake slices side by side, they will have opposite signs for the velocity component perpendicular to the screen.

For us to have an axisymmetric flow, additionally to the idea of unchanging of field as we rotate, we need to forbid any kind of transport normal to the faces of the cake (i.e. normal to the screen, in the second image above).